# How to use 'in' clause in salesforce ajax query?

Tags: soql, javascript, ajax, ajax-toolkit

In document.ready method i am doing this

```
var setIds=new Array() //array of saleforce ids
$(sel).each(function() {
     setIds.push("'"+$(this).attr('id')+"'");                                                                                    
});
var myquery = "SELECT Id,Name, Body from Attachment where Id in ("+setIds+")";
alert(myquery);
result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);                                
records = result.getArray("records");
alert(records.length);
```

My problem is, even i am passing set of ids to the query it is just returning 1 record.

Any guess why this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,I tried the same but its not working.I get malformed query exception and Bind variables only allowed in apex.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether the javascript side of things has the smarts to deal with the set or not, but you could just generate the full text query yourself:

```
var setIds=new Array() //array of saleforce ids
var ids = '';

$(sel).each(function() {
  ids = ids + '"' + $(this).attr('id') + '",';
});

if(ids.length > 1) {
  ids.substr(0, ids.length - 1);
}
var myquery = "SELECT Id,Name, Body from Attachment where Id in (" + ids + ")";
alert(myquery);
result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);                                
records = result.getArray("records");
alert(records.length);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.join` instead... but it's good.

Comment: I thought there was a method for that but couldn't remember it off the top of my head last night!

Comment: @LaceySnr my code worked when i removed body column from the query, i don't know why such a behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I never used Apex AJAX Toolkit but I think You can do something like this -

```
var myquery = "SELECT Id,Name, Body from Attachment where Id in:setIds";
```

In Apex query you can't pass set as an argument you we have to convert it into list. but i am not sue about AJAX Toolkit.

Comment: I copied my query from browser console and pasted into SF developer console it worked fine there. The query is like this SELECT Id,Name, Body from Attachment where Id in ('00P11000000JrbDEAS','00P11000000JqIoEAK')

Comment: So your problem resolved?

Comment: No, it is returning only 1 record.