# How to Include an "IN" clause to SOQL when using via forcetk

Tags: soql, rest-api, forcetk

I'm working on a Salesforce Hybrid mobile application and there I need to perform an SOQL query with some filters. All are working but an **IN** clause.

```
$j('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.week_group').each(function(){
        if($j(this).is(':checked')){
            dynamicQueryData.selectedWeeks.push($j(this).val());
        }
    });
selectedWeekList = dynamicQueryData.selectedWeeks.join(", ");
var dynamicQuery = "SELECT Id, Name FROM My_Obj__c WHERE Start_Date__c = THIS_YEAR AND Status__c ='Pending' AND CALENDAR_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Start_Date__c))=1 AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Start_Date__c)) IN :(" + selectedWeekList + ") AND custom_user__c = 'some_id'  ORDER BY Start_DateTime__c";
forcetkClient.query(dynamicQuery, onSuccess, onError);
```

It's throwing **bind variables only allowed in apex code** expetion. Found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29055/how-to-use-in-clause-in-salesforce-ajax-query) somewhat similar post but no luck. I tried LaceySnr's suggestion, but still the same error. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use of a colon means the system is expecting a bind variable, you're correctly putting in parentheses and creating a comma separated list, so removing the colon should do the trick:

```
// this: 
AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Start_Date__c)) IN :(" + selectedWeekList + ")

// becomes: 
AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(convertTimeZone(Start_Date__c)) IN (" + selectedWeekList + ")
```

Depending on how your values are represented (i.e. if they're strings), you'll need to surround each item in the list with single quotes as well if they're not already there.

Comment: Doh! some mistakes are so pathetic ;) Thanks a lot @LaceySnr

Comment: A single wrong character is usually the hardest thing to spot :)

Comment: Wish I could vote up your comment 1000 times @LaceySnr